# Losing (realtime) permission when sudoing from root to myself

Tags: security, sudo, udev, real-time, jack

After an upgrade to debian wheezy (I did not upgrade the kernel - it is still  3.8.2) I can no longer start jackd in the way I used to do it. I get `you are not allowed to use realtime scheduling`.

My investigation show, that this is related to a `sudo` command in my script, where I sudo from root to martin. The sudo is required, because I start jackd when my firewire mixing console gets switched on, using an udev rule. I can reproduce the problem by typing sudo from the commandline.

In short, this is what I observe

- start jackd as martin -> works
- start jackd as root -> works
- login as root and `su - martin`, then start jackd -> works
- as root `sudo -u martin /usr/bin/jackd ...` -> does not work
- as above but `sudo -E -u martin ...` -> does not work

My /etc/security/limits.conf contains  these lines

```
@audio - rtprio 40
@audio - nice -20
@audio - memlock 1554963
```

`sudo -u martin id` shows that I am in the audio group, however root is not. After sudoing from root to martin, martin has no realtime permissions

```
sudo -u martin sh -c "ulimit -e -r"
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
real-time priority              (-r) 0
```

Adding root to the audo group made no difference. Root still has no realtime permissions and after `sudo -u martin`  martin still looks as above

Comment: Do you normally run the command as martin (using to sudo to get to root permissions) or do you run it as root and use `-u martin` to run jack as martin? As martin does `sudo ls` (my logic here is that your sudoers file may have been changed on upgrade and does not have an entry to allow martin to use sudo?

Comment: The usual way to run it as root and use -u martin, as the script is invoked by udev. Other than that martin can run sudo commands just fine because he is in the sudoers file as martin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: sudo is _usually_ used for non-root users to get to root privileges. Have you tried `su - martin -c /usr/bin/jackd ...` instead?

Comment: That did the trick. Apparently the behavior of sudo has changed. Feel like writing an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that sudo is preserving your environment of the root user, and therefore may not have paths or other environment variables that the `martin` user has set. It may be also that you need to run `jack` via sudo from a shell with the `-s /path/to/shell` option.

However as root, you have the rights to `su` (substitute user) without being prompted for a password (and not require configuration of sudo to achieve this, sudo is specifically aimed at non-root users).

```
 su - martin -c /usr/bin/jackd ...
```

`-c` tells su what command to run, and the `-` option (which can also be done via `-l`) will attempt to set up the environment similar to that of the user it is being ran as (in this case `martin`).

Comment: I didn't verify your explanation, but su - sure did the trick.

Comment: I'm glad it sorted your issue though! :)